# Check for existing AD group members doesn't work in PowerShell

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have a 50% working script for adding users to AD Groups. But I can't the part to work where it needs to check if they are already member of that group.

See below the failing part:

```
ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
$Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Recursive | where {$_.objectclass-eq “user”} | Select sAMAccountName

        If ($Members -contains $User) {
            Write-Host "$User is already member of" Test.$Space.Admin
        }
```

If a user is already member of the AD Group, it does not provide me with an update.

See below the complete code:

```
$Space = "MS"
$ADMAccount = "john.smith","jane.smith"
$USRAccount = "john.doe","jane.doe"
$VWRAccount = "something.special","other.user"
$Groups = "Test.$Space.Admin","Test.$Space.Users","Test.$Space.Viewers"

Write-Host "Adding users to AD Groups now..." -ForegroundColor White

ForEach ($User in $ADMAccount){
    ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
        $Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Recursive | where {$_.objectclass-eq “user”} | Select sAMAccountName

        If ($Members -contains $User) {
            Write-Host "$User is already member of" Test.$Space.Admin
        }
        Else {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Test.$Space.Admin" -Members $ADMAccount
        }
    }
}

ForEach ($User in $USRAccount){
    ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
        $Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Recursive | where {$_.objectclass-eq “user”} | Select sAMAccountName

        If ($Members -contains $User) {
            Write-Host "$User is already member of $Group"
        }
        Else {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Test.$Space.Users" -Members $USRAccount
        }
    }
}

ForEach ($User in $VWRAccount){
    ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
        $Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Recursive | where {$_.objectclass-eq “user”} | Select sAMAccountName

        If ($Members -contains $User) {
            Write-Host "$User is already member of $Group"
        }
        Else {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Test.$Space.Viewers" -Members $VWRAccount
        }
    }
}

Write-Host "Adding users to AD Groups completed..." -ForegroundColor Green
```

Thanks in advance,
Roland

Comment: Swap  `If ($Members -contains $User)` for  `If ($Members.samaccountname -eq $User)`

Comment: @Drifter104 Tried your approach, but didn't work...

Comment: strange, I could reproduce what you are getting but adding the `.samaccountname` then produced the required text for me

Comment: Why do you check if a user is already a member of a group? You can just `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Test.$Space.Viewers" -Members $ListOfVWRAccounts` and it will work. (Based on a random Add-ADGroupMember cmdlet from your code)